# Correct way of sticking to the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I'm trying to have a `ul` and a `span` elements to stick to the bottom of their containing `div`. The only way I managed to so is through setting them with `position:relative` and playing with `bottom: x` for each element separately (according to its size).

Is there a more standard way to do it?

Here is the code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt9uqtgw/)

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="top_menu">
        <span id="logo">TechSystems</span>
        <span id="sub_logo">think smarter</span>
        <div id="menu_content">
            <ul>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>about</li>
                <li>contact us</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to #menu_content:

```
#menu_content
{
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/x7p35mrz/

Comment: thanks... but adding the suggested code didn't really made a difference.